# ExtJS chart.series.add is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have recently migrated from ExtjS 4 to 5.1.
My charts application will dynamically create the chart using chart.series.add function and chart.axes.items.  This application was running fine with ExtJS4.2

With ExtJS5.1, I am getting this error:  chart.series.add is not a function.
Even chart.series.clear is also giving same exception.

Can any one please help on how to add series and axes dynamically to CartesianChart?

Thanks,
Valli

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says it's [`chart.addSeries(series)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.AbstractChart-method-addSeries)